# Xamarin forms - InputStream lose some bites, won't read all data

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-bluetooth

I'm a beginner programmer, but I like challenges. During these challenges I encountered a problem.

I am building a device based on Raspberry Pi, I want to control it from a smartphone. The choice fell on communication via Bluetooth. I pair and connect two devices without any problems, I send data from Android to RPi without any problems.The problem appears when sending data from RPi, short messages are sent correctly, but sending more data causes a problem. InputStream loses 990 bytes, I noticed that one data packet is just that many bytes.

Here's my code

```
        public static void ListenForData()
    {
        InStream = socket.InputStream;
        byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int dataBytes;
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] fileBuffer;
            try
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    while (InStream.CanRead || InStream.IsDataAvailable())
                    {
                        dataBytes = InStream.Read(dataBuffer);
                        ms.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBytes);
                        fileBuffer = ms.ToArray();
                        File.WriteAllBytes(Path + "c.jpg", fileBuffer);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I use the BluetoothChat example to send messages and it works in their case, but sending an image, for example, results in the error described above.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
It turned out that I run the listening thread twice. In two places, and in only one, I added the option to check if the thread is already working. After correcting this error, everything works.